# Restassured request with spec doesn't get response status logged

Tags: java, rest-assured, status

I want my Restassured request with spec get response status logged.
My request is

```
given()
                .spec(requestSpec)
                .when()
                .get("/" + userId)
                .then()              
                .spec(responseSpec)
                .extract().as(User.class)
                ;
```

My spec is

```
    public static ResponseSpecification responseSpec = new ResponseSpecBuilder()
            .expectStatusCode(200)
            .log(STATUS)
            .log(BODY)
            .expectBody(notNullValue())
            .build();
}
```

But there is no response status in the log unless I add `.log().status()` to my request.

Pls tell me how can I fix this.

UPDATE
Following Ashish Patil advice I updated my request but without result

```
LogConfig logconfig = new LogConfig().enablePrettyPrinting(true);
RestAssured.config().logConfig(logconfig);


given()
        .spec(requestSpec)
        .when()
        .get("/" + userId)
        .then()              
        .spec(responseSpec)
        .extract().as(User.class)
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Question didn't specify if you have set `LogConfig` before declaring your responseSpec. So you might need to declare `LogConfig` first to use `log` method as mentioned in [doc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/5.1.0/io/restassured/builder/ResponseSpecBuilder.html#log-io.restassured.filter.log.LogDetail-) :

```
LogConfig logconfig = new LogConfig().enablePrettyPrinting(true);
RestAssured.config().logConfig(logconfig);
```

And afterwords you can declare your `responseSpec` as per your question.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, edited my initial post

Comment: Well, can you try declaring `LogConfig`  before declaring `ResponseSpecification` ? so please use above call before you have declared `ResponseSpecification` & see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a bug. `ResponseSpecification` only supports one `LogDetail` at a time. For example:

```
...
.log(STATUS)
.log(BODY)
...
```

--> it will log BODY, not STATUS, because it is a variable declared
`private LogDetail responseLogDetail`, the latter value will override the previous value.

```
  ResponseSpecificationImpl logDetail(LogDetail logDetail) {
    this.responseLogDetail = logDetail
    this
  }
```